# Saving Torch Hub's SSD inferenced images in an output directory

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm using [Pytorch SSD](https://pytorch.org/hub/nvidia_deeplearningexamples_ssd/) that loads a pre-trained model on the COCO dataset from Torch HUB. Modified the code in an API format to fetch some images and detect the objects in it.

Trying to save each inference image output in the `/output` using matplotlib's `.savefig()` method but getting an error:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class ObjectDetector:

    def __init__(self):
        self.precision = 'fp32'
        self.detect_model = torch.hub.load('NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_ssd', model_math=self.precision)
        self.utils = torch.hub.load('NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_ssd_processing_utils')

    def process(self):
        self.fetch_images()
        self.create_model()
        self.display_detections()
        

    def fetch_images(self):
        """To get the images from a website"""
        self.images = ['http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000397133.jpg','http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000037777.jpg','http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000252219.jpg']

        return self.images

    def create_model(self):
        self.detect_model.to('cuda')
        self.detect_model.eval()

        self.inputs = [self.utils.prepare_input(uri) for uri in self.images]
        tensor = self.utils.prepare_tensor(self.inputs, self.precision == 'fp16')

        with torch.no_grad():
            detections_batch = self.detect_model(tensor)

        results_per_input = self.utils.decode_results(detections_batch)
        self.best_results_per_input = [self.utils.pick_best(results, 0.40) for results in results_per_input]
        self.classes_to_labels = self.utils.get_coco_object_dictionary()

        return self.best_results_per_input, self.classes_to_labels

    def display_detections(self):
        
        output_dir = "../data/vision/ssd/output"
        
        for image_idx in range(len(self.best_results_per_input)):
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
            # Show original, denormalized image...
            image = self.inputs[image_idx] / 2 + 0.5
            ax.imshow(image)
            # ...with detections
            bboxes, classes, confidences = self.best_results_per_input[image_idx]
            for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
                left, bot, right, top = bboxes[idx]
                x, y, w, h = [val * 300 for val in [left, bot, right - left, top - bot]]
                rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
                ax.add_patch(rect)
                ax.text(x, y, "{} {:.0f}%".format(self.classes_to_labels[classes[idx] - 1], confidences[idx] * 100), bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))
        
            plt.savefig(output_dir + str(image) + '.jpg')
        plt.show()


if __name__== '__main__':
    det = ObjectDetector()
    det.process()
    del det
```

The above code throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-acbe775772c1> in <module>
     63 if __name__== '__main__':
     64     det = ObjectDetector()
---> 65     det.process()
     66 
     67     del det

<ipython-input-9-acbe775772c1> in process(self)
     14         self.fetch_images()
     15         self.create_model()
---> 16         self.display_detections()
     17 
     18 

<ipython-input-9-acbe775772c1> in display_detections(self)
     57                 ax.text(x, y, "{} {:.0f}%".format(self.classes_to_labels[classes[idx] - 1], confidences[idx] * 100), bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))
     58 
---> 59             plt.savefig(output_dir + str(image) + '.jpg')
     60         plt.show()
     61 

~/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    721 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
    722     fig = gcf()
--> 723     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    724     fig.canvas.draw_idle()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
    725     return res

~/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in savefig(self, fname, transparent, **kwargs)
   2201             self.patch.set_visible(frameon)
   2202 
-> 2203         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   2204 
   2205         if frameon:

~/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   2117 
   2118             try:
-> 2119                 result = print_method(
   2120                     filename,
   2121                     dpi=dpi,

~/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    356                 f"%(removal)s.  If any parameter follows {name!r}, they "
    357                 f"should be pass as keyword, not positionally.")
--> 358         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    359 
    360     return wrapper

~/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_jpg(self, filename_or_obj, dryrun, pil_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    597             pil_kwargs.setdefault("quality", rcParams["savefig.jpeg_quality"])
    598             pil_kwargs.setdefault("dpi", (self.figure.dpi, self.figure.dpi))
--> 599             return background.save(
    600                 filename_or_obj, format='jpeg', **pil_kwargs)
    601 

~/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2153                 fp = builtins.open(filename, "r+b")
   2154             else:
-> 2155                 fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
   2156 
   2157         try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/vision/ssd/output[[[0.1050852  0.07895297 0.08367175]\n  [0.31462591 0.31466424 0.32513717]\n  [0.28277484 0.25506944 0.23508735]\n  ...\n  [0.42182888 0.27386384 0.07784647]\n  [0.67421166 0.57844825 0.39889071]\n  [0.554919   0.33316082 0.09618731]]\n\n [[0.05228582 0.03646781 0.0400054 ]\n  [0.06949542 0.06235639 0.05692344]\n  [0.25959795 0.18080175 0.18654409]\n  ...\n  [0.60428691 0.30419598 0.06168084]\n  [0.62523846 0.37480789 0.15464491]\n  [0.40595506 0.21335363 0.0789785 ]]\n\n [[0.10904118 0.11286539 0.09207947]\n  [0.0804173  0.04945466 0.03713621]\n  [0.24569849 0.12457102 0.1002835 ]\n  ...\n  [0.8473525  0.49805938 0.01584464]\n  [0.62128949 0.34659926 0.04259144]\n  [0.60784509 0.39757653 0.1146472 ]]\n\n ...\n\n [[0.54990582 0.37598903 0.20369267]\n  [0.5526588  0.38010985 0.19625383]\n  [0.56226779 0.38371096 0.20185737]\n  ...\n  [0.29863339 0.2165191  0.14226269]\n  [0.30894688 0.23059896 0.16393229]\n  [0.31879315 0.21973148 0.16671452]]\n\n [[0.54124921 0.37518263 0.19985079]\n  [0.54947818 0.38385507 0.19607851]\n  [0.54889008 0.37478852 0.18892228]\n  ...\n  [0.29478525 0.22002212 0.15326277]\n  [0.31478406 0.23243116 0.16062237]\n  [0.30818757 0.21890863 0.14786195]]\n\n [[0.53892612 0.37097071 0.1888549 ]\n  [0.54983966 0.38421659 0.19571689]\n  [0.55770917 0.38090676 0.18950984]\n  ...\n  [0.316164   0.24439232 0.16849774]\n  [0.32127783 0.23892493 0.16441515]\n  [0.30470566 0.21542674 0.14437993]]].jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.savefig()` can be saved like this. Also, to generate a random unique string, `import uuid` can be used.

```
def display_detections(self):
    
    output_dir = "../data/vision/ssd/output"
    
    for image_idx in range(len(self.best_results_per_input)):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
        # Show original, denormalized image...
        image = self.inputs[image_idx] / 2 + 0.5
        ax.imshow(image)
        # ...with detections
        bboxes, classes, confidences = self.best_results_per_input[image_idx]
        for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
            left, bot, right, top = bboxes[idx]
            x, y, w, h = [val * 300 for val in [left, bot, right - left, top - bot]]
            rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
            ax.add_patch(rect)
            ax.text(x, y, "{} {:.0f}%".format(self.classes_to_labels[classes[idx] - 1], confidences[idx] * 100), bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig(output_dir + "/" + "Image" + "_" + str(uuid.uuid4()))
    plt.show()
```